# Error When Taking Comments With Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get reviews from the tripadvisor site. There are 5 reviews on each page. And selenium is required to move to the next page. But I want to do this with beautifulsoup. First of all, the tripadvisor page of any hotel is like this.

```
url="https://www.tripadvisor.com.tr/Hotel_Review-g312737-d500556-Reviews-Flamingo_Hotel_Spa-Oludeniz_Mugla_Province_Turkish_Aegean_Coast.html"
```

This is the first page, when you want to go to the second page, you put the numbers in the form of 'or5 or or10' ('Reviews-or5-Flamingo') in the middle of the place where it says 'Reviews-Flamingo'. As the page goes forward, it increases in multiples of 5. First, I put a 'for' loop in the 'Reviews' section and then increasing in the middle of it in multiples of 5.

My code block looks like this:

```
def tripadvisor():
parca=url.split('Reviews')
page1=parca[0]
page2=parca[1]    
for i in range(0,15,5):
         yorumlar = []
        #  html=requests.get(f'{url}-or{i}').content
         html=requests.get(f'{page1}or{i}{page2}').content
         soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
         list = soup.find_all("q",{"class":"IRsGHoPm"})
         for div in list:
             yorum = div.find("span").text
             yorumlar.append(yorum)
             data=pd.DataFrame(yorumlar)
             print(data.head())
```

What I got here is as follows:

```
0 Ölüdenizde bulduğumuz en temiz otellerden biri…
0
0 Ölüdenizde bulduğumuz en temiz otellerden biri…
1 Iki gun konaklama gerceklestirdik. Oncelikle f…
0
0 Ölüdenizde bulduğumuz en temiz otellerden biri…
1 Iki gun konaklama gerceklestirdik. Oncelikle f…
2 Eşim ile birlikte otelde 12-15 Ağustos tarihle…
0
0 Ölüdenizde bulduğumuz en temiz otellerden biri…
1 Iki gun konaklama gerceklestirdik. Oncelikle f…
2 Eşim ile birlikte otelde 12-15 Ağustos tarihle…
3 Otel konumu çok iyi . Personeller çok ilgili, …
0
0 Ölüdenizde bulduğumuz en temiz otellerden biri…
1 Iki gun konaklama gerceklestirdik. Oncelikle f…
2 Eşim ile birlikte otelde 12-15 Ağustos tarihle…
3 Otel konumu çok iyi . Personeller çok ilgili, …
4 gayet güzel ve nezih bir otel . özellikleri ye…
```

The comments are coming back piece by piece. Does anyone know why?where am I making mistakes. Are there friends to help?

Comment: This is just what you asked it to do.  For every comment, you add the comment to your larger list, then create a dataframe from the accumulated list, then print that dataframe.  I'm pretty sure you want those last two lines to be indented out one spot, so they are not part of the inner `for div` loop.

Comment: And, by the way, when constructing your URL, you are not adding the page number like you said (`reviews-or5-Flamingo`).  Instead, you are REPLACING the word "Reviews" with your "or" number.  It just so happens the web site accepts that.

Comment: I'm a little confused.Can you help with a code block

Comment: Look at the code.  For every tag that matches your class, you get the text of that tag, then append it to your list (`yorumlar`), then convert that list to a dataframe, then print the dataframe.  If there are 5 items, you will print the list after you get the 1st, then again after you get the 2nd, then again after you get the 3rd, etc.  The last two lines should not be part of that loop.  Delete 4 spaces at the beginning of each line.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the indentation.

```
def tripadvisor():
    parca=url.split('Reviews')
    page1=parca[0]
    page2=parca[1]    
    for i in range(0,15,5):
         yorumlar = []
         #  html=requests.get(f'{url}-or{i}').content
         html=requests.get(f'{page1}or{i}{page2}').content
         soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
         list = soup.find_all("q",{"class":"IRsGHoPm"})
         for div in list:
             yorum = div.find("span").text
             yorumlar.append(yorum)
         data=pd.DataFrame(yorumlar)
         print(data.head())
```